# Is it possible to add a custom HTTP referer to an iframe on a 3rd party website

Tags: iframe, http-headers, http-referer

I am embedding YouTube videos as:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" style="background:url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/54545454/hqdefault.jpg) 50% 50% / cover" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/54545454"></iframe>
```

I have also removed all http-referers being sent from the website. So YouTube does not know where the video has been loaded from.

Is there a way to add a custom http referer to iframe embeds?